# TypeError at /accounts/register/ encode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterations'

Tags: python, django, hash, passwords

I do not understand why I get this error because I did not delete anything in the encode(). It does not let me submit my registration form. Can anybody help?

traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Documents\tryFOUR\src\register\views.py" in register
  13.           user = form.save(commit=False)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Documents\tryFOUR\src\custom_user\forms.py" in save
  50.       user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in set_password
  105.         self.password = make_password(raw_password)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py" in make_password
  84.     return hasher.encode(password, salt)
```

hashers.py :

```
def encode(self, password, salt, iterations):
        Sweetwords = ['road,models,table']
        Sweetwords.extend(honey_gen.gen(password, base9, [passfile.txt]))
        for i in range(base10):
            Sweetwords.extend(honeywordtweak.tweak(passwords[i], 3))
            random.shuffle(Sweetwords)

        hashes = [ ]
        for swd in sweetwords:
            hashes.append(self.hash(swd, salt, iterations))
            self.honeychecker.update_index(salt, Sweetwords.index(password))
            h = Sweetwords(salt = salt, Sweetwords = pickle.dumps(hashes))
            h.save()
            return "%s$%d$%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, iterations, salt, hashes[0])
```

I'm so confused, I do not know what I did wrong.

----EDITED----

```
class MyHoneywordHasher(PBKDF2PasswordHasher):
    algorithm = "honeyword_base9_tweak3_pbkdf2_sha256"
    iterations = 36000
    digest = hashlib.sha256

    def salt(self):
        salt = get_random_string()
        while Sweetwords.objects.filter(salt=salt).exists():
            salt = get_random_string()
        return salt

    def verify(self, password, encoded):
        algorithm, iterations, salt, dummy= encoded.split('$', 3)
        hashes = pickle.loads(Sweetwords.objects.get(salt=salt).Sweetwords)
        hash = self.hash(password, salt, int(iterations))
        if hash in hashes:
            return honeychecker.check_index(salt, hashes.index(hash))
            return False
```

settings.py :

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'honeywordHasher.hashers.MyHoneywordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
]
```

Comment: You sure you added the HoneyWordHasher in PASSWORD_HASHERS in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

From the last line of the traceback (`return hasher.encode(password, salt)`), it looks like hashesr.py just not passing an `iterations` argument. To solve this, you could just hardcode it into the function.

Comment: What do you mean by hardcode it into the call ? Can you explain ? Sorry for troubling you

Comment: Something like `hasher.encode(password, salt, 10)`, where 10 can be replaced with whatever number of iterations.

Comment: Maybe try removing it from the function's arguments and just coding it into the function instead

Answer (score 0):

Please add :

```
‘honeywords.hashers.HoneywordHasher'
```

at the top of PASSWORD_HASHERS setting var in settings.py.

Comment: I put 'honeywordHasher.hashers.MyHoneywordHasher' MyHoneywordHasher is my class in the hashers.py . Is that triggering the error ? @RajKris

Comment: You ave a settings.py file in your root folder. In that you will have a var called PASSWORD_HASHERS defined. Add ‘honeywords.hashers.HoneywordHasher' at the top. This is mentioned in the pdf link :https://www.rsaconference.com/writable/presentations/file_upload/dsp-w02-honeywords-a-new-tool-for-protection-from-password-database-breach_final.pdf

Comment: unfortunately, it will give an error " no module passlib" . my honeyword app called : honeywordHasher and my defined class is: MyHoneywordHasher . i follow django documentation for the PASSWORD_HASHER @RajKris